# ManyToMany и CascadeType.ALL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Есть таблица `A`, таблица `B` и таблица `A_B`, которая используется для ассоциации. Есть соответствующие сущности:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {
    @Id
    int id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "A_B",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "b_id")}
    ) 
    public List<B> list;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {
    @Id
    int id;
}
```

Если получить несколько объектов типа `B` из базы и добавить их в `list` объекта `A`, а потом сохранить объект `A`, то кидается следующее исключение:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.example.B#342] are being merged.
```

С чем это связано и как это исправить?

**Добавил пример**

```
B b1 = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM B b WHERE some_condition", B.class).getSingleResult(;
A a1 = new A();
a1.getList().add(b1);
B b2 = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM B b WHERE some_condition", B.class).getSingleResult(;
A a2 = new A();
a2.getList().add(b2);
em.merge(a1);
em.merge(a2);
```

Comment: пример кода можно, где ексепшн валит? И попробуйте вместо `cascade = ALL` указать `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}`

Comment: Пример кода добавил. Если указать без MERGE, то нарушается Primary Key (a_id, b_id) на таблице A_B.